# Greensock - Multiple, consequent tweens on a single object

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I animate a div's position, then back to it's origin  with a different ease:

```
var anim_a = new TimelineMax().to($(".mybox"), 3, {x: 400}).stop();
var anim_b = new TimelineMax().to($(".mybox"), 1, {x: 0, ease:Bounce.easeOut}).stop();
```

Problem is after both the animations ran once, they wont run anymore, why? and how can I repeat them on demand?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mquw7p0L/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var anim_a = function() {
  var anm = new TimelineMax().to($(".mybox"), 1, {
    x: 400
  }).stop();
  anm.play();
}
var anim_b = function() {
  var anm = new TimelineMax().to($(".mybox"), 1, {
    x: 0,
    ease: Bounce.easeOut
  }).stop();
  anm.play();
}

$(".run-a").click(function(e) {
  anim_a();
});

$(".run-b").click(function(e) {
  anim_b();
});
```

```css
.run-a,
.run-b {
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mybox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<div class="run-a">Go</div>
<div class="run-b">Go back</div>

<div class="mybox"></div>
```

i am not used to this TimeLineMax. Still i made a small change to the code and now its working as said. Please check and confirm whether this will fit for your context. I just made anim_a  and anim_b as two functions with play operation included.